# Reading from an EFS volume without mounting it

Tags: amazon-efs

I am currently trying to get data off of an EFS volume through a lambda and I would like to create an access_point to do that since it is the way that AWS seems to recommend (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) but there are some complications which make that path unavailable to me for the short term. I understand that I could also mount the EFS volume to an EC2 instance and then use SSM to read the data, but I am being told that I can just write a simple python script to read the data from EFS using it's DNS endpoint.

My question is "Is this actually possible?" I haven't seen any solutions online for EFS saying to use EFS with lambda, just do a http request like you would for an s3 file. Since it's a NFS, it seems like you would need to mount it.

Any help understanding if I'm missing something here would be appreciated.